# Who tipped off Freddy Thorne?

Tags: peaky-blinders

I watched season 2 and I haven't found answer yet (maybe I missed it) to the mystery from season one:
Who tipped off Freddy Thorne when he went to visit his wife in labour and police picked him up?
Tommy, when accussed, looked genuinly surprised. In fact, he asked Campbell later on who did it and Campbell answered sarcastically: you, of course, everyone knows it.